# Querying based on JSON array sub element

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, psql

Tried multiple answers from here and elsewhere and couldn't find the right answer yet.

```
create table mstore (
muuid uuid PRIMARY KEY,
msid text,
m_json JSONb[] not NULL
);
```

inserted first row:

```
insert into mstore (muuid, msid, m_json) values (
'3b691440-ee54-4d9d-a5b3-5f1863b78755'::uuid,
'<163178891004.4772968682254423915@XYZ-73SM>',
(array['{"m": 123, "mts": "2021-09-16T10:53:43.599012", "dstatus": "Dropped", "rcpt": "abc1@xyz.com"}']::jsonb[])
);
```

inserted second row:

```
insert into mstore (muuid, msid, m_json) values (
'3b691440-ee54-4d9d-a5b3-5f1863b78757'::uuid,
'<163178891004.4772968682254423915@XYZ-75SM>',
(array['{"m": 125, "mts": "2021-09-16T10:53:43.599022", "dstatus": "Dropped", "rcpt": "abc3@xyz.com"}']::jsonb[])
);
```

updated the first row:

```
update mstore
set m_json = m_json || '{"m": 124, "mts": "2021-09-16T10:53:43.599021", "dstatus": "Delivered", "rcpt": "abc2@xyz.com"}'::jsonb
where muuid = '3b691440-ee54-4d9d-a5b3-5f1863b78755';
```

Now table looks like:

```
               muuid               |                          msid                          |                                                                                                                 m_json                                                                                                                  
--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3b691440-ee54-4d9d-a5b3-5f1863b78757 | <163178891004.4772968682254423915@XYZ-75SM> | {"{\"mid\": 125, \"rcpt\": \"abc3@xyz.com\", \"msg_ts\": \"2021-09-16T10:53:43.599022\", \"dstatus\": \"Dropped\"}"}
 3b691440-ee54-4d9d-a5b3-5f1863b78755 | <163178891004.4772968682254423915@XYZ-73SM> | {"{\"mid\": 123, \"rcpt\": \"abc1@xyz.com\", \"msg_ts\": \"2021-09-16T10:53:43.599012\", \"dstatus\": \"Dropped\"}","{\"mid\": 124, \"rcpt\": \"abc2@xyz.com\", \"msg_ts\": \"2021-09-16T10:53:43.599021\", \"dstatus\": \"Delivered\"}"}
```

Now, I need to query based on the status. I tried few but most relevant one was

```
select * from mstore,jsonb_array_elements(m_json) with ordinality arr(item_object, position)  where item_object->>'{"dstatus": "Delivered"}';
```

and

```
select * from mstore where m_json @> '[{"dstatus": "Delivered"}]';
```

Neither work, as they have syntax errors. How to run this query with dstatus values?

Comment: I think you cant query this way with SQL, but it is possible to query data in an array using NoSQL(firebase firestore).

Comment: It works in this blog https://levelup.gitconnected.com/working-with-a-jsonb-array-of-objects-in-postgresql-d2b7e7f4db87
But not for my problem. But for sure, the blog is able to query using JSON Array's sub element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `mstore.m_json` is a Postgres array of JSONB elements and not a JSONB array and therefore `unnest` must be used rather than `jsonb_array_elements`. Also have a look at `->>` operator in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html).
The same applies to your second example. It would work if `mstore.m_json` is a JSONB array and not a Postgres array of JSONB elements.

```sql
select m.muuid, m.msid, l.item_object, l.pos
from mstore m
cross join lateral unnest(m.m_json) with ordinality l(item_object, pos)
where l.item_object ->> 'dstatus' = 'Delivered';
```

It would be better to use JSONB data type for column `mstore.m_json` rather than JSONB[] or - much better - normalize the data design.